# how to make div visible using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

```
 function showwaitmsg() {
        $("#wait").fadeIn();
        return  true;
    }
    function hidewaitmsg() {
        $("#wait").fadeOut();

    }

    $("a:contains('Test1')").bind("click", function () {
      if (showwaitmsg())
        test2(); // Function contains XMLHttpRequest
        hidewaitmsg();
    });


   <div id="wait" class="overlay" style="display: none">
             Please Wait
        <img src="~/loading.gif" />
    </div>
```

I am trying to show a "please wait" message using the above code while the XMLHttpRequest is being processed. The wait div is showing up too late after the request has been processed. Can you please tell me what I should do to make the wait div visible as soon as the test1 button is clicked?

Comment: remove the `hidewaitmsg()` call and put it in the success call of your ajax request. Ajax is async so your hide message gets processed right away

Comment: Post the code for `test2()` - best way is probably to use the callback function from the `XmlHttpRequest` to do your `fadeOut()` call

Comment: Use the jQuery Ajax .always function, so the message gets hidden in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `showwaitmsg()` and `hidewaitmsg()` outside of `test2()`, you should include them inside your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    beforeSend: showwaitmsg(),
    ...,
    complete: hidewaitmsg()
});
```

Returning false in the `beforeSend` function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the `beforeSend` option will be called regardless of the type of request.
It is also worth noting that `complete` is called after `success` and `error` callbacks are executed.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#id_of_button").on('click', function() {
    $("#wait").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to move this code to the AJAX call itself, like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    ...,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#wait').fadeIn();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#wait').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

It will help to separate the logic correctly and support more ways to make such AJAX call in your code, e.g. pressing keyboard button, etc.